# If I added a Service Based database to my solution, what do I do when I publish the application?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, database

I've added a service based database to my solution.

So, it's working on my system and everything is dandy. However this program will have to run on many many machines all independent to each other (meaning they don't connect or even know they exists) I'm selling the application to different people all over my country.

What exactly do I have to do so my application has access to the database design and uses it?

I might be asking the wrong question, but hopefully with my use case you can guide me. Thanks!

Comment: So does each instance of the application create it's own database or do all instances use a central database?

Comment: Each application 'owns' its own database. They are not aware of other installations anywhere. It's just a simple scanning application. No need for communication outside of the computer.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to install the relevant database engine with the correct service name, and create the database and relevant objects on installation.

Overall probably not a good solution unless you really need a fully fledged database engine, and even then i local database might be easier.

Bear in mind that the installation of a serious database engine often has complication which would baffle the average PC user.

Can't you use something like sqllite, or berkelydb?

What exactly are the requirements?

Comment: The requirements are very lax. "I want the program to save my things and be able to see them on the software whenever." That means I can use pretty much anything I want to save information. I'm using Microsoft SQL database because I want to learn Linq-to-SQL as well.